# Interator and average in C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, average

I'm trying to learn to use iterator with vectors in C++ by, for example computing the average of a vector.

Yet this code does not give the proper answer and I cannot figure out why !

```
double average(vector<double> const &v)
{
    vector<double>::size_type taille = v.size();
    double sum = 0;
    for(vector<double>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        sum += v[*i];

    return sum/taille;
}
```

Can anybody give me a hint ?

Thanks a lot in advance ! Bye :)

Comment: By the way, you can divide the result of `std::accumulate` by `size()` in the case of real code.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, iterators imitate the behaviors of pointers (to some degree). So if `it` is an iterator to an element, you access the element by *dereferencing* it as `*it`.

That means, instead of this:

```
sum += v[*i];
```

you should write this:

```
sum += *i; //just dereference the iterator!
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing vector items through an iterator is simply `*i`, not `v[*i]`. The form you've used requires accessing with index:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) sum += v[i];
```

And your code should look like:

```
for(vector<double>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
    sum += *i;
          ^^^^ note this
```

Answer (score 1):

The iterator actually points to the object. Proper way to iterate is:

```
double average(vector<double> const &v)
{
    vector<double>::size_type taille = v.size();
    double sum = 0;
    for(vector<double>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        sum += *it;

    return sum/taille;
}
```

In C++11 you can do this too:

```
double average(vector<double> const &v)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for(const double &d : v)
        sum += d;

    return sum/v.size();
}
```